# Loop doesn't execute until keyboard is pressed

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

So I have this node.js script which is  supposed to get mouse position and move it few times. The problem is that my loop executes 1 time and then it just stops and does nothing, but it also doesn't end the script(It just shows blinking underline in new line). When I press something on keyboard script executes all lasting times and script ends like it should be. So where might be the problem?

```
var robot = require("robotjs");

for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    var mouse=robot.getMousePos();
    console.log("Mouse is at x:" + mouse.x + " y:" + mouse.y);
    robot.moveMouse(mouse.x,mouse.y+100);
    robot.mouseClick();
}
```

Comment: so I ran your script and it worked just fine for me

Comment: I figured it out its all about where i left my cursor if its on cmd it will click cmd and that will stop script if its somewhere on screen it will run good Ty for help question is answered.